# Cannot to add HtmlParser in ParseContex in TIKA

Tags: java, html-parsing, apache-tika

I use Tika FACADE: tika-core v1.25, tika-parsers v1.25.

I need to redefine the Html Parser for full control over the html document processing process.

To do this, I created a CustomHtmlParser class and want to pass it for processing, but in such a way as not to change the processing for other files.

Now CustomHtmlParser extends HtmlParser,

Finding Files:
CustomHtmlParser:
package com.mycompany.stackexp.CustomParsers;

HtmlParser:
package org.apache.tika.parser.html;

Code for processing any types:

```
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(curFile.getInputStream())
    AutoDetectParser parser = AutoDetectParser();
    ParseContext pc = new ParseContext();
    Metadata metadata = Metadata();
    Tika tika = new Tika();

    String mimeType = tika.detect(is); //определяем mimeType нашего документа
    metadata.set(Metadata.CONTENT_TYPE, mimeType);//устанавливаем mimeType

    CustomBodyContentHandler ch = new CustomBodyContentHandler(-1);
    ch.setRoot(fileName); //Установить root

    //init my htmlParser
    init_customHtmlParser();

    parser.parse(is, ch, metadata, pc);
```

Under the word: does not work, it is assumed that when saving CustomHtmlParser in ParseContext, when processing an html document, there will be a transition to my parse method (inside the CustomHtmlParser class). But in fact, there is a transition to the standard parse method (inside the HTMLParser class).Or by some other method redirect the processing to my class

Tell me how you can make a parser and replace the already created parser. Or by some other method redirect the processing to my class. My goal: either replace HTMLParser with CustomHtmlParser or add a new class.

I try to add my parser in pc (ParseContext):

```
//v1
public void init_customHtmlParser(){
    //My new parser which extends HtmlParser
    CustomHtmlParser customHtmlParser = new CustomHtmlParser();
    pc.set(HtmlParser.class, customHtmlParser);
}

//v2
public void init_customHtmlParser(){
    //My CustomHtmlParser save as HtmlParser
    HtmlParser customHtmlParser = new CustomHtmlParser();
    pc.set(HtmlParser.class, customHtmlParser);
}
```

But in the debugger I see that my class is not active.
I see that each time the HTMLParser class is selected, not my CustomHtmlParser class.

Why did I decide that this could help me?
I use customEmbeddedDocExtractor and I add it through this code:

```
if (pc.get(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.class) == null) {
    Parser p = pc.get(Parser.class);
    if (p == null) {
        pc.set(Parser.class, parser);
    }

    this.customEmbeddedDocExtractor = new CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor(pc);
    customEmbeddedDocExtractor.saveCustomBodyContentHandler(ch);
    customEmbeddedDocExtractor.setRoot(fileName);
    pc.set(EmbeddedDocumentExtractor.class, customEmbeddedDocExtractor);
}
```

- EmbeddedDocumentExtractor in package org.apache.tika.extractor;
- customEmbeddedDocExtractor in package com.mycompany.stackexp;

Public CustomParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor extends ParsingEmbeddedDocumentExtractor.

And when working with Custom Parsing Embedded Document Extractor, everything is added and works as expected.